# Zoom in on a 2D graph

Tags: plotting, graphics, front-end, graphs-and-networks, gui-construction

I have seen many queries on zooming in on plots etc. But I haven't seen any regarding 2D graphs. For eg if I have a graph like

```
Graph[{1->2, 2->3, 3->1}].
```

It will create a graph. I have a similar graph which is very complex which has vertices very close by. I want to zoom in on a set of nodes and see how they are related. I can increase the image size or decrease the vertex size, but both of them are not helping since the graph is pretty huge and has a complex network of nodes which are clustered together and connected to each other. I can use `NeighbourhoodGraph` function. But is there any way to zoom in on the graph itself to see the how the nodes are connected to each other?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do this using `Show` and `PlotRange` which can be used in combination with graphs. To determine the full `PlotRange` of the original Graph you could use `AbsoluteOptions` to determine the values of the `VertexCoordinates` of the graph. The function `CoordinateBoundingBox`, introduced in V10.1, is helpful here:

```
SeedRandom[1110];
g = RandomGraph[{70, 200}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{xrange, yrange} =  VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates] 
                      // CoordinateBoundingBox // Transpose
(* {{0., 5.33683}, {0., 4.09534}}  *)
```

An interactive example of zooming:

```
zoomGraph[g_Graph] :=
 DynamicModule[{pt},
  pt = VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates] // CoordinateBoundingBox;
  Row[
   {
    LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
     Dynamic[
       Show[
         g, 
         Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Red], Rectangle @@ pt}], 
         ImageSize -> 400
       ]
      ]
    ],
    Dynamic[Show[g, PlotRange -> Transpose[pt], ImageSize -> 400]]
    }
   ]
  ]

zoomGraph[g]
```

[image]

In some cases, the zoomed-in vertices may become too big: you could reduce the vertex size as follows:

```
zoomGraph[Graph[g, VertexSize -> 0.5]]
```

or add a `VertexSize` to the zoomed-in graph.

Comment: How can I use this feature with Graphics[] instead?

Answer (score 30):

This is a prototype, it can not handle `Text` `Inset` and some more complicated directives efficiently but I don't have time / motivation to improvie it.

---

Here's something fun:

```
g = Normal @ Show @ CommunityGraphPlot[
     ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "DolphinSocialNetwork"}]
];
```

[image]

```
dist = Normalize[#] (2./Pi ArcTan[Norm[5 #]]) &;

DynamicModule[{drag,pts,prims}
 ,
 pts = Union@Cases[g, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, \[Infinity]];

 prims = (
    First[g] /. Thread[# -> Range@Length@#] &@pts)/. FilledCurve -> (# &);

 Panel@Column[{EventHandler[
     Graphics[{
          GraphicsComplex[ Dynamic[dist /@ pts], prims]
      }, 
      ImageSize -> 500, 
      PlotRange -> 1], 
  {"MouseDown" :> {drag = {MousePosition@"GraphicsScaled"}}, 
   "MouseDragged" :> {drag = {Last@drag, 
          MousePosition@"GraphicsScaled"};
        pts = (# + 5 (#2 - # & @@ drag) & /@ pts)}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Fun indeed.  What parameter do I change to modify the magnitude of the fish-eye effect?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The multiplier in `dist` inside `Norm` should be enough.

Comment: @Kuba +1 looks awesome, I was wondering if it would be possible to make this solution more generically applicable? Say, how could I pass a `Graph` and receive output as above?

Comment: @E.Doroskevic I was trying but labels are placed weirdly because "next to" after transformation may be "next to something else". There were also some other minor issues, I will try to back to that when I have more ideas and time. Thanks for feedback :)

Comment: @Kuba I appreciate that, thank you! I think this is a brilliant way to visualize large network graphs. Hope you will find a way to develop this idea forward!