# How-to make large graph more readable?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

One day, I found myself curious about different topics in mathematics. So, I stumbled uppon a [website](http://www.math-prof.com/) (*considerably old website*) where author has tabularized mathematics into subjects and associated topics.

Based on the information taken from the website, I decided to make a `Graph` to see how do different subjects and topics relate.

I managed to load the data:

```
web = Import["http://www.math-prof.com/", "Data"];
```

and retrieve the data:

```
rawData = web[[2]][[2 ;; All]];
```

From the above raw set of data, I have retrieved all subjects:

```
subjects = If[(Length @ #) > 1, List @ First @ #, List @ #] &  [First @  rawData [[#]]] & /@ Range @ ((Length @ rawData) - 1); (*-1 because I wasn't interested in Physics bit*)
```

The topics were a bit more troublesome so some manual work has been carried out to clean-up the [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z3y3yzhbrbv7r8v/sample.zip?dl=0)

From the above set of files, I carried out an `Import`:

```
topics = Import[ "t" <> ToString @ # <> ".txt", "List"] & /@ Range @ 12;
```

Finally, creating a graph:

```
Graph[Flatten @ Table[Rule[subjects[[i]] // First , #] & /@ topics[[i]], {i, Length @ subjects}], VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line"]
```

Here is the output:

[image: output]

I was wondering how I could make this `Graph` more readable? As you see, the `Text` is practically unreadable.

Comment: Why not have the subjects be `Tooltip[]`s instead?

Comment: I will try and implement that just now, thanks for the suggestion @J.M

Comment: Try some of the zooming techniques detailed here [104718](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104718).

Comment: Thanks @Edmund, that looks pretty awesome