# is there a way to draw curves in same graph with zoom?

Tags: plotting, graphics

[image]

i have a data as x and y table and i want to produce a curve showing me all points with zoom if possible , i used listplot[] as shown below :

ListPlot[{c, d, e, f, h, g, x, y(*,s*)}, Joined -> True,
  PlotLegends -> {"F" , "M", 
    "MB", "p", "S", 
    "L", "LB", "PS", "E"}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio];

the graph was not clear for the values of y-axis
for example if c has values at 6 and {d,e,f,g,x} has values at 1 or 1.5,0.5 ,0.01 and 2
the curves obtains all on the axis except c

Comment: You will get help, provided you place your code in the Mathematica form, and give the data to enable one to reproduce your result. You can go to help/Tour at the top of the page to learn, how to do that. It would be further helpful, if you give a sketch (it might be e.g., a hand-drawn one) of what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica has [build-in zoom](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/RotateZoomAndPanGraphics.html) for 3D. but for 2D, you'd have to make your own (as far as I know). Here is very basic example:

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, from, to}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray],
 {{from, -2 Pi, "from?"}, -2 Pi, 0, .1},
 {{to, 2 Pi, "to?"}, 0, 2 Pi, .1}
 ]
```

For more advanced example, see [how-to-zoom-and-pan-a-listlineplot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21583/how-to-zoom-and-pan-a-listlineplot) and  [zoom-in-on-a-2d-graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104718/zoom-in-on-a-2d-graph)